# How should I handle proxying HTTP requests with many invalid URLs

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, proxy

I need to create a proxy for an application my team is working on that we can use to intercept requests to certain domains and return specific content (mostly mocked content, sometimes debugging information included, etc...) if certain conditions within the request are met (e.g., certain auth headers, remote address range, etc...).

For requests that do not need to be diverted to our development environment, I want them be sent to the original intended target. How I started implementing this initially was to use a ProxyService that would take a HttpServletRequest and using Apache HttpClient 4.3,  submit the request and return the response as a string to be evaluated (we sometimes modify the content to make debugging easier).

I am running into a number of issues where the request URI is littered with invalid characters. At first I tried using URL to reconstruct the URI with things like URLEncoder.encode for each fragment of the URI path, file, query string values, etc... but I quick was hit with another issue.

Some of the origin servers for these requests do not check if the URL is encoded and end up failing when they are.

e.g.,

```
http://www.example.com/file.php|x=1|y=2,z=3
https://www.example.com/some/path?foo=[{"x":"1"}]
https://www.example.com/some/path;x=1;y=2/stuff|foo|bar|baz/here
```

I have tried breaking the path into fragments and encoding each fragment and appending them to a string builder to recreate the URI but then I discovered that some of the services choke when they receive an encoded URL.

I'm relatively green when it comes to handling problems like this with Java, and I'm not sure where I should be looking for a solution.

Details about the application:

Spring Boot app using Spring 4 MVC
Embedded Tomcat 8 servlet

What would be ideal is if there was some way I could just take the HttpServletRequest object, and transparently proxy that to the original host with minimal changes, this way the headers, content, parameters, etc... were all preserved, but I would still be able to access the response content to modify for development.

What I really want to try and avoid is having to write and maintain a service class that handles normalizing and sanitizing these URIs myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can classify this (writing a reverse proxy) as a generally Hard Problem in any language. The client-side HTTP libraries in Java are full of quirks, which to be fair is probably only a reflection of the fact that HTTP is not really all that simple a protocol. You might end up having to implement, or at least understand in more detail than you would like, the whole thing to do a good job of the proxy problem. The clients will frustrate you sometimes by trying to be too clever (e.g. caching connections and cookies, or following redirects). The only sensible choice for the client is the Apache Commons one, but its API isn't very stable, and the documentation is sparse.

I've had to do reverse proxying a number of times in a Spring app, but never found a library that did it out of the box. I've always ended up with special cases that I was sure would work in the specific situations for which they were written for (because I could test them fairly exhaustively, and watch their behaviour in production), but was never convinced that they would stand up as generic solutions. [Here's one](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/login-server/blob/master/login-server/src/main/java/org/cloudfoundry/identity/uaa/login/RemoteUaaController.java#L472) that is pretty close to generic (maybe), but I'm sure suffers from problems (not the least of which being I have not dealt with streaming of large response bodies).

Excerpt from the above (it uses Spring `RestTemplate` and Apache `HttpClient`):

```
protected ResponseEntity<byte[]> passthru(HttpServletRequest request, HttpEntity<byte[]> entity,
                Map<String, Object> model) throws Exception {

    String path = extractPath(request);

    HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    requestHeaders.putAll(getRequestHeaders(entity.getHeaders()));
    requestHeaders.remove(COOKIE);
    requestHeaders.remove(COOKIE.toLowerCase());
    // Get back end cookie if saved in session
    String cookie = (String) model.get(COOKIE_MODEL);
    if (cookie != null) {
        logger.debug("Found back end cookies: " + cookie);
        for (String value : cookie.split(";")) {
            requestHeaders.add(COOKIE, value);
        }
    }

    ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = defaultTemplate.exchange(getUaaBaseUrl() + "/" + path,
                    HttpMethod.valueOf(request.getMethod()), new HttpEntity<byte[]>(entity.getBody(),
                                    requestHeaders),
                    byte[].class);
    HttpHeaders outgoingHeaders = getResponseHeaders(response.getHeaders());
    return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(response.getBody(), outgoingHeaders, response.getStatusCode());

}
```

Comment: I wanted to follow up on this after a little experimentation. Apache `HttpClient` was able handle about 80% of the requests and I was able to raise that to about ~95% simply using `HttpURLConnection`. Ultimately I've decided the effort involved isn't worth the liability. 1-2% failure could mean 100k+ broken requests so I've decided to move the proxying out of the app. Varnish is sitting in front of the app and on a 305 (Use Proxy) response it uses a transparent Squid proxy as the backend. Here's the ProxyService https://gist.github.com/corycomer/944725400afa0abf8906 thanks a lot for the help!